# Broken thumbnails in YouTube v3

Tags: youtube-api

I have been trying to get the new thumbnail setting feature to work in the v3 Data API. There is documentation on how to set thumbnails (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails), but it doesn't seem to be available as a resource in the actual API when I call it.

I wondering if there is a bug somewhere or if the thumbnail setting code has been documented and just not yet released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is working as expected. Make sure you use the latest libraries from https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/libraries

Comment: Hi Mr.Ibrahim, I know I shouldn't do this in comment section but are you one of the team member doing Youtube API v3 development? I actually experience some problem on searching for particular channel's videos ordered by date, I have also filed a bug on that but receives no attention. Is there any other way I can notify that to development team?

Comment: Issue tracker is the best way to go. Issues are prioritized are we are trying to respond to them as much as we can. What's the issue number?